# How to clear the select option on click to (x) button in Vue.js?

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

How do I create a function or button for a clear select option field? I try with

```
 <input type="reset" value="x" />
```

but when I clear one field, all fields are cleared. I'm not sure if you need my code with basic select fields? I accept in any way

Answer (score 1):

It can be solved manually using [event handlers](https://v1.vuejs.org/guide/events.html). Do:

```
<input value="x" @click="clearOneField" />
```

And in your methods hook inside script, implement your method:

```
clearOneField() {
  this.field = null;
}
```

Comment: Did I need for every field separate function?

Comment: You can turn the method more general using the variable name as param and doing `this[nameOfVar] = null`

Comment: Okey for all field i must have v-model ?

Comment: Yes! v-model associates the value of your input with some local variable

Answer (score 1):

Let's take this example. You could do it using v-model:

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>

<div id="app">
  <p>{{ message }}</p>
  <select v-model="select">
    <option value="">None</option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
  </select>
  <button v-on:click="clear">x</button>
</div>

<script>
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    selectvalue: ''
  }
})
</script>
```

fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/vpqnh9dt/

Comment: This is good, but do I need some parameter to refer to a particular choice of options?

Comment: What if I have 5 select option ? How to reference on selected?

Answer (score 0):

@option:deselecting="deselecting"

add event deselecting

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).